# Why is the end() element in Associative container print the same value as the last element?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

In the code below, the value that the iterator points to is the same for both the last and the second last element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    set<int> s1 = {4,3,2,5,1};
    set<int>::iterator i;
    
    i = s1.end();
    cout << *i << endl; // 5
    
    i--;
    cout << *i << endl; // 5
    
    
    cout << *s1.end() << endl;  // 5
    cout << *(--s1.end()) << endl;  // 5
    
    return 0;
}
```

In my understanding the value pointed to by the end element should be null.
Why is this so?

Comment: *"In my understanding the value pointed to by the end element should be null"* - even if that were true (which it is not), dereferencing a null pointer invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: The target is for `vector`, but it's the same thing really, there's nothing special about associative containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You invoked undefined behavior, [std::set::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end)

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the
> set.
> This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in
> undefined behavior.

---

[Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) renders the entire program meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

> In my understanding the value pointed to by the end element should be null. Why is this so?

Why your understanding is wrong I cannot tell ;). Snarkyness aside: No. There is no "end element". The `end` iterator points to one past the last element. You cannot dereference it. If you do you invoke undefined behavior.

The last element in a container is typically refered to as the "back" and many containers have a `back()` method to access it.

Answer (score 0):

> In my understanding the value pointed to by the end element should be null. Why is this so?

It isn't.

The one-past-the-end iterator doesn't "point" to anything; it's not dereferencable.

C-strings might appear at first to be an exception to this rule, but they're not: they are logically terminated by a `NULL` character that you can check for, but that `NULL` is still part of an array of `char` objects, and you cannot dereference a `char*` that's the one-past-the-end iterator for that array. Think of a C-string's null terminator as a "this page deliberately left blank"; the page doesn't give you any more story, but it's still a page.

> Why is the end() element in Associative container print the same value as the last element?

That's one possible result of a program with undefined behaviour.